# PhoneGap: Added Animated gif to index. Works on test devices but not from app store downloads

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, app-store

I have added a short animated gif that appears after the splash screen on my project as a bit of an intro. I tested on the simulator and on my provisioned phone and it works fine but on the version I uploaded to the app store the image has disappeared - I am left with just a blank space.

Does Apple not allow this? Is there a proper way to do this?

I am using Jquery to display and hide the image. Is that not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

animated gifs are scheduled for a future release. It won't support right now.